# Cоздать несколько идентичных form при нажатии кнопки и сделать их submit

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Данные которые будут вбиты в эти инпуты, должны быть после записаны в базу данных.
Нажимая на кнопку , должна появляться ниже указанная форма. Но надо сделать так, что бы пользователь мог при нажатии на кнопку создать форму, заполнить ее и создать еще одну форму(с теми же полями) и сделал ее SUBMIT.

```
<a id="ico-plus"/></a>
<div id="education-fields">
    <form method="POST">
        Name of School / University</br>
        <input name="education_school_name" maxlength="100" type="text" class="field text fn" value="">
        </br>Faculty, Study Direction</br>
        <input name="education_faculty" maxlength="150" type="text" class="field text fn" value="">
        </br>Degree, Level of Education</br>
        <input name="education_level" maxlength="100" type="text" class="field text fn" value="">
        </br>About Your Education Life</br>
        <textarea name="education_about" spellcheck="true" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
        </br>Enter Starting and Ending Dates:</br>
        <input name="education_started" type="date" class="field text fn" value="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="education_ended" id="education-ended-true" value="now">Are you still learning there?</br>
        <input name="education_ended" id="education-ended-field" type="date" class="field text fn" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

Как, после того как пользователь забил одну или несколько форм, записать ее в базу данных?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. По теме выходит, вы хотите готовое решение от скрипта на стороне клиента, до AJAX-запросов и скрипта на стороне сервера. Уточните. Вопрос про скрипт у клиента или комплекс? Нужно именно на jQuery у клиента и PHP на сервере? Поймите, вариантов масса. Я бы по своему вкусу склонился бы к [tag:knockoutjs] у клиента и [tag:sails.js] + [tag:node.js] или [tag:cakephp] на сервере. Писать серверную часть с запросами к БД на чистом PHP просто лень, откровенно говоря =)

Comment: Я пытаюсь написать на пхп

Comment: Вот смотрите, к примеру я добовляю несколько идентичных форм в education-fiеlds, но когда я буду их записывать в бд(допустим я добавил две формы), каждая форма пойдет в свой row, со своим id, в mysql. Но пока я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Слушайте, я ответ, конечно, примерный написал, но вам имеет смысл смотреть в сторону готовых фреймворков, того же [CakePHP 2](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html). Они из коробки умеют делать  все эти вещи с буквально несколькими строками от вас. А ещё лучше смотрите в сторону Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Даже не знаю, с чего начать. Вы уж простите мою дерзость, что я начинаю с банального, но думаю имеет смысл с ввода ключевых слов в Google, например "php mysql примеры". И вот сразу же отличный пример сохранения http://phpfaq.ru/formtable.

Отправлять сразу несколько форм не получится в общем случае. Можно скриптом перебрать формы, сериализовать их через [jQuery .serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) и отправить общий запрос через POST. Но это кривизна. Knockout с его observables вообще подобные штуки делает из коробки. В вашем случае, когда надо, так сказать, проще, я бы делал одну форму, поля называл бы

Первый ряд:

```
<input name="data[0][education_school_name]" type="text" value=""/>
<input name="data[0][education_faculty]" type="text" value=""/>
```

Второй ряд:

```
<input name="data[1][education_school_name]" type="text" value=""/>
<input name="data[1][education_faculty]" type="text" value=""/>
```

и т.д.

В этом случае, когда вы отправите форму, PHP распознает её как

```
array( 'data' => array( 
                  0 => array('education_school_name' => 'moscow',
                             'education_faculty' => 'dance'),
                  1 => array('education_school_name' => 'school 568',
                             'education_faculty' => 'painting')
                     )
      )
```

Т.е. вы отправляете не несколько одинаковых форм, а одну форму, но массивом. Вы отправите массив из строк. А в PHP вы уже перебираете массив, обрабатываете как надо, проверяете поля и сохраняете в MySQL.

Comment: Спасибо! Это мне и надо было! Сейчас попробую

Comment: @DimonVersace Будьте добры, если ответ подошёл, поставьте соответствующую галочку =)

Comment: Подошел) Вы помогли студенту в создании дипломки. Спасибо